# How to make multidimensional list from the values coming from for loop

Tags: python

There are two loops in my code one main for loop which will read some ip address from list of ip addresses and second loop is where i am sending some commands to those ips and getting some output(required) and i am sending two commands and getting two outputs from those commands.Here firstly I am separating those outputs using split(,) method and appending it to a list using append method.I am getting output near to my desired output but not getting exact or expected output.Please help me to get that output.

Here i am using Python list related methods to get output.

```
cli_commands = ['sh version | i p n|Cisco IOS','sh inventory']
for k in range(len(cli_commands)):
    net_connect.send_command(cli_commands[k])
    vall=net_connect.send_command(cli_commands[k])
    #myList2.extend(vall.strip().split(","))
    #myList2.append(vall.split(","))
    myList2.append(vall.strip().split(","))
```

Actual result:

```
[['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)'], ['NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC1452X5C5'], ['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)'], ['NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-48TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC1502Z4G1']]
```

Here external loop will get ip address and go to inner forloop where it will execute two commands one by one and ['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)'] will come from first command and

```
['NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC1452X5C5']
```

will come from other command from loop.

Expectations:

```
[['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)','NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC1452X5C5'], ['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)','NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-48TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC1502Z4G1']]
```

Comment: Format your post please.

Comment: Please provide sample data from command sh version | i p n|Cisco IOS','sh inventory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below as the last line:

```
print([myList2[i] + myList2[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(myList2), 2)])
```

Output:

```
[['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)','NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC1452X5C5'], ['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)','NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-48TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC1502Z4G1']]
```

Comment: This is working for me thanks and can you please explain this and also if more then 2 commands output is there what need to be done.

Comment: @user3420561 It simply gets all the even numbers, 0, 2, 4, 6 and so on.. and get's the value with that, and the value with that + 1 togther

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(myList2[0::2], myList2[1::2])]
```

With your given example:

```py
In [15]: myList2 = [['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE
    ...: SOFTWARE (fc3)'], ['NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FOC
    ...: 1452X5C5'], ['Cisco IOS Software', ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', ' Version 15.0(2)SE11', ' RELEASE
    ...:  SOFTWARE (fc3)'], ['NAME: "1"', ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-48TS-L  ', ' VID: V02  ', ' SN: FO
    ...: C1502Z4G1']]

In [16]: [x + y for x, y in zip(myList2[0::2], myList2[1::2])]
Out[16]:
[['Cisco IOS Software',
  ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)',
  ' Version 15.0(2)SE11',
  ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)',
  'NAME: "1"',
  ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  ',
  ' VID: V02  ',
  ' SN: FOC1452X5C5'],
 ['Cisco IOS Software',
  ' C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)',
  ' Version 15.0(2)SE11',
  ' RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)',
  'NAME: "1"',
  ' DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-48TS-L  ',
  ' VID: V02  ',
  ' SN: FOC1502Z4G1']]
```